# Help improve my my python code for Exponential Smoothing Sumitted to Statsmodel

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, statistics

I just submitted [this pull request](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/1287) to [`statsmodels`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels) (a Python toolkit for statistical and econometric modeling). It adds support for [exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) of time series.

I have only been programming for a few months. I am not very good with Numpy, and just learning classes and decorators, so any help would be appreciated.

The main part of the code is below. Can anyone help with shortening this so it is more efficient? Especially around the `for` loop. [The complete file is here.](https://github.com/ccsv/statsmodels/blob/81f99f5b87f57ed5f6942a9b8582257558c3722f/statsmodels/tsa/Expsmoothing)

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tools.eval_measures as em

#debug use
numpy.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

def exp_smoothing(y, alpha, gamma, delta=0, cycle=None, damp=1, initial=None,
                  trend='additive', forecast=None, season='additive', output='data'):
    '''
    Exponential Smoothing
    This function handles 15 different Standard Exponential Smoothing models

    Parameters
    ----------
    y: array
        Time series data

    alpha:  float
        Smoothing factor for data between 0 and 1.

    gamma: non zero integer or float
        Smoothing factor for trend generally between 0 and 1

    delta: non zero integer or float
        Smoothing factor for season generally between 0 and 1

    cycle: int
        Length of cycles in a season. (ie: 12 for months, 4 for quarters)

    damp: non zero integer or float {default = 1}
        Autoregressive or damping parameter specifies a rate of decay
        in the trend. Generally 0>d>1

    initial: str, {'3avg'}(Optional)
        Indicate initial point for bt and y
        default:     bt = y[0]-y[1],    st = y[0]
        3avg:        Yields the average of the first 3 differences for bt.

    trend: str, {'additive','multiplicative', 'brown'}
        Indicate model type of trend default is 'additive'

        additive: uses additive models such as Holt's linear & Damped-Trend
        Linear Exponential Smoothing. Generalized as:
        s_t = a * y_t + (1-a) * (s_t-1 + b_t-1)
        b_t = g *(s_t - s_t-1) + (1 - g) * b_t-1

        multiplicative: uses multiplicative models such as Exponential trend &
        Taylor's modification of Pegels' model. Generalized as:
        s_t = a * y_t + (1-a) * (s_t-1 * b_t-1)
        b_t = g *(s_t / s_t-1) + (1 - g) * b_t-1

        brown: used to deal with the special cases in Brown linear smoothing

    forecast: int (Optional)
        Number of periods ahead.

    season: str, {'additive','multiplicative'}
        Indicate type of season default is 'additive'

    output: str, {'data', 'describe','forecast'}(Not implemented)


    Returns
    -------
    pdata: array
        Data that is smoothened using model chosen

    Notes
    -----
    This function is able to perform the following algorithms:
        Simple Exponential Smoothing(SES)
        Simple Seasonal models (both multiplicative and additive)
        Brown's Linear Exponential Smoothing
        Holt's Double Exponential Smoothing
        Exponential trend method
        Damped-Trend Linear Exponential Smoothing
        Multiplicative damped trend (Taylor  2003)
        Holt-Winters Exponential Smoothing:
        multiplicative trend, additive trend, and damped models for both
        multiplicative season, additive season, and damped models for both

    References
    ----------
    *Wikipedia
    *Forecasting: principles and practice by Hyndman & Athanasopoulos
    *NIST.gov http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc433.htm
    *Oklahoma State SAS chapter 30 section 11
    *IBM SPSS Custom Exponential Smoothing Models
    '''

    #Initialize data
    y = np.asarray(y)
    ylen = len(y)
    if ylen <= 3:
        raise ValueError("Cannot implement model, must have at least 4 data points")
    if alpha == 0:
        raise ValueError("Cannot fit model, alpha must not be 0")
    #forcast length
    if forecast >= 1:
        ylen += 1

    #Setup array lengths
    sdata = np.zeros(ylen - 2)
    bdata = np.zeros(ylen - 2)

    # Setup seasonal values
    if type(cycle) is int:
        if ylen < 2 * cycle:
            raise ValueError("Cannot implement model, must be 2 at least cycles long")
        #Setting b1 value
        bdata[0] = np.mean((y[cycle:2 * cycle] - y[:cycle]) / float(cycle))
        #Setup initial seasonal indicies
        #coerce cycle start lengths
        if len(y) % cycle != 0:
            cdata = y[:len(y) % cycle*-1].reshape(-1, cycle)
        else:
            cdata = y.reshape(-1, cycle)
        cdata = (cdata / cdata.mean(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)).mean(axis=0)
        cdata = np.concatenate([cdata, np.zeros(ylen - 3)])
    else:
        #Initialize to bypass delta function with 0
        cycle = 0
        cdata = np.zeros(ylen)

    #Setting b1 value
    if gamma == 0:
        bdata[0] = 0
    elif initial == '3avg':
        bdata[0] = np.mean(abs(np.diff(y[:4])))
    else:
        bdata[0] = abs(y[0] - y[1])

    #Setting s1 value
    sdata[0] = y[0]

    #Equations & Update ylen to align array
    ylen -= 3
    for i in range(ylen):
        s = sdata[i]
        b = bdata[i]
        #handles multiplicative seasons
        if season == 'multiplicative':
            if trend == 'multiplicative':
                sdata[i + 1] = alpha * (y[i + 2] / cdata[i]) + (1 - alpha) * s * (b**damp)
                bdata[i + 1] = gamma * (sdata[i + 1] / s) + (1 - gamma) * (b ** damp)
                cdata[i + cycle] = delta * (y[i + 2] / sdata[i + 1]) + (1 - delta) * cdata[i]
        #handles additive models
            else:
                sdata[i + 1] = alpha * (y[i + 2] / cdata[i]) + (1 - alpha) * (s + damp * b)
                bdata[i + 1] = gamma * (sdata[i + 1] - s) + (1 - gamma) * damp * b
                cdata[i + cycle] = delta * (y[i + 2] / sdata[i + 1]) + (1 - delta) * cdata[i]
        else:
            if trend == 'multiplicative':
                sdata[i + 1] = alpha * (y[i + 2] - cdata[i]) + (1 - alpha) * s * (b**damp)
                bdata[i + 1] = gamma * (sdata[i + 1] / s) + (1 - gamma) * (b ** damp)
                cdata[i + cycle] = delta * (y[i + 2] - sdata[i + 1]) + (1 - delta) * cdata[i]
            #handles additive models
            else:
                sdata[i + 1] = alpha * (y[i + 2] - cdata[i]) + (1 - alpha) * (s + damp * b)
                bdata[i + 1] = gamma * (sdata[i + 1] - s) + (1 - gamma) * damp * b
                cdata[i + cycle] = delta * (y[i + 2] - sdata[i + 1]) + (1 - delta) * cdata[i]
                #debug
##                print 'period=', i ,'cdata=', cdata[i+cycle],'sdata=', sdata[i]

    #Temporary fix: back fill data with Nan to align with y
    filx = [np.nan,np.nan]
    bdata = np.concatenate([filx, bdata])
    sdata = np.concatenate([filx, sdata])
    if season == 'multiplicative':
        if trend == 'multiplicative':
            pdata = (sdata * bdata) * cdata[:len(cdata) - cycle+3]
        else:
            pdata = (sdata + bdata) * cdata[:len(cdata) - cycle+3]
    else:
        if trend == 'multiplicative':
            pdata = sdata * bdata + cdata[:len(cdata) - cycle+3]
        #Handles special case for Brown linear
        elif trend == 'brown':
            at = 2 * sdata - bdata
            bt = alpha / (1 - alpha) * (sdata - bdata)
            sdata = at
            bdata = bt
            pdata = sdata + bdata + cdata[:len(cdata) - cycle+3]
        else:
            pdata = sdata + bdata + cdata[:len(cdata) - cycle+3]

    #Calculations for summary items (NOT USED YET)
    x1 = y[2:]
    x2 = pdata[2:len(y)]
    rmse = em.rmse(x1,x2)

    #forcast
    if forecast >= 2:
        #Configure damp
        if damp == 1:
            m = np.arange(2, forecast+1)
        else:
            m = np.cumsum(damp ** np.arange(1, forecast+1))
            m = m[1:]

        #Config season
        if cycle == 0:
            if season == 'multiplicative':
                c = 1
            else:
                c = 0
        elif forecast > cycle:
            raise NotImplementedError("Forecast beyond cycle length is unavailable")
        else:
            c = cdata[ylen+1:]
            c = c[:forecast-1]

        #Config trend
        if season == 'multiplicative':
            if trend == 'multiplicative':
                fdata = sdata[ylen] * (bdata[ylen] ** m) * c
            else:
                fdata = sdata[ylen] + m * bdata[ylen] * c
        else:
            if trend == 'multiplicative':
                fdata = sdata[ylen] * (bdata[ylen] ** m) + c
            else:
                fdata = sdata[ylen] + m * bdata[ylen] + c
                #debug
##                print 'fdata=', fdata, 'sdata=', sdata[ylen], 'm=', m, 'bdata', bdata[ylen], 'c=', c

        pdata = np.append(pdata, fdata)
        #debug
        print 'fdata=', fdata
        print 'sdata=', sdata
        print 'bdata=', bdata
        print 'cdata=', cdata
        print 'pdata=', pdata
        return pdata
    else:
        print 'sdata=', sdata
        print 'bdata=', bdata
        print 'cdata=', cdata
        print 'pdata=', pdata
        return pdata
```

Here is the test data and to check it is [here](http://analysights.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/forecast-friday-topic-double-exponential-smoothing/) everything in blue

```
#-------Test-------
#(y, alpha, gamma, delta = 0, cycle = None, damp = 1, initial = None,
#                     trend = 'additive', forecast=None, season = 'additive', output='data')
y=[152,176,160,192,220,272,256,280,300,280,312,328]


exp_smoothing(y,0.2, 0.3,0,None,1, None, 'additive', 3)
```

Comment: You have cut out all the documentation from the code you posted. How do you expect us to review it without knowing what it is supposed to do or how to use it? Please restore the documentation!

Comment: @Gareth Rees You can download the code at github where the pull is.

Comment: We'd like you to post all the code that you want reviewing here. [See the help](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "If you want a code review, you must post the relevant snippets of code in your question." And obviously the documentation is a relevant part of what you want us to review.

Comment: @GarethRees Alright I will post the documentation for the main function that does all the work. But I am not posting the wrappers because they just make it easier to implement specific conditions. It would be too long.

Comment: Thank you — documentation for `exp_smoothing` is fine.

Comment: @GarethRees Just a basic question would something like this be better for a class? I never really wrote classes or decorators much so I am not very familiar with implementing them.

Comment: I would say that a function is a better fit that a class for this; generally, functions do something and classes are something, and your code is doing something.

Answer (score 2):

Some quick comments just based on reading the documentation and the first few lines:

1. Typos, inconsistencies, and omissions:

   - The first line should be a summary of the behaviour of the function, not a title, so something like "Exponentially smooth a time series".
   - There's no need for capital letters in "Standard Exponential Smoothing" or in "Damped-Trend Linear Exponential Smoothing".
   - There's an extra space in "alpha:  float".
   - In "Smoothing factor for data between 0 and 1" there needs to be punctuation between "data" and "between". (A similar comment applies to some other parameters.)
   - Does "between 0 and 1" include the endpoints or not?
   - Sometimes you have a full stop at the end of sentences and sometimes you don't.
   - "non-zero" needs a hyphen.
   - "Length of cycles in a season" should be "*Number* of cycles in a season".
   - Write "i.e.," instead of "ie:", but in this case I think "for example," would be better.
   - What does "generally between 0 and 1" mean?
   - "0>d>1" is an impossible condition.
   - What is "bt"?
   - "Indicate model type of trend default is 'additive'" make no sense in English.
   - "used to deal with the special cases" — deal with them how?
   - "Number of periods ahead" — ahead of what?
   - "Not implemented" — suggests that this code is not ready for merge.
2. You write, "This function is able to perform the following algorithms" but you don't say how. It would be worth explaining what parameters to pass in order to get each of these behaviours.
3. I don't like the way you've used the word "season". In English a "season" is one fourth of a year, or, metaphorically, one part of a cycle. But in "Length of cycles in a season" you appear to be using the word to mean the whole cycle. This can only be confusing to the reader.
4. You've left in a lot of debugging print statements. But these should surely be removed before issuing the pull request. It looks as though it would be worth your while learning to use Python's debugging facilities, then you wouldn't need to use debugging print statements.
5. `alpha` needs to be "between 0 and 1", but all you actually check is `alpha == 0`.
6. Some of the other parameters have restricted values. For example, `trend` must be `'additive'`, `'multiplicative'`, or `'brown'`, but you don't actually check its value.
7. Generally it's best to check all your parameters first, rather than doing half the computation and then checking some of the parameters.
8. You asked whether "something like this [would] be better for a class?" A class represents a group of *things* with common behaviour. But you don't seem to have any thing here, so there's no need for a class.